# How to get random numbers for user ID using Random Number Generator in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Not able to generate random number in RIDE. How to use a random number generator in robot framework?

I tried this for scalar variable -

```
Evaluate random.randint(0, sys.maxint)
```

it is returning the same text, not returning the number.

Do I need to install any library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised the `randint()` doesn't work for you - did you use the correct syntax, `Evaluate` must point/end with the external module you're using, "random" in this case?

```
${ran int}=    Evaluate    random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)    random
Log     This is a random number between 0 and 9223372036854775807: ${ran int}
```

By the way, [Python 3 does not have `sys.maxint`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers)  - it has `sys.maxsize`, which if also available in Python 2. You'd better use it, to future-proof your code.

---

Anyways,  the String library has a keyword [`Generate Random String`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String) you can use for the same purpose. By passing an argument `[NUMBERS]` the string will have only numbers in it (which you can convert to an integer):

```
${ran int}=    Generate Random String    length=4    chars=[NUMBERS]
${ran int}=    Convert To Integer    ${ran int}
Log     This is a random number between 1000 and 9999: ${ran int}
```

The drawback is the length of the string is of fixed length - you can't generate (easily, without some math) a number in the range 0...x, only numbers in the same magnitude (e.g numbers of 4 digits, like in this sample).